# Unbound Breakpoints?

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

[image]

I've been having trouble running some breakpoints after my code is built and ran. My project is on ASP.NET. I'm using VS 2022 and so far I have tried the following things:

- Restart VS and delete all my breakpoints
- Clean my solutions (Build > Clean Solution)
- Delete `.vs` folder
- Restart computer

To be specific, the breakpoint is solid when set, but becomes hollow and unbound when my code is ran. Any suggestions? How can I fix this?

Comment: I am having the same issue with Visual Studio 2022.  One additional thing I noticed in my case is that if I remove and re-add the breakpoint after debugging has started and everything is loaded, the breakpoint will work.  But as soon as I stop and start debugging again, it will be disabled (unbound).   This never happened with VS2017, on the same project.  The accepted answer does not work in my case.

Comment: @Backslider, same for me too. This must be a bug in Visual Studio. Does anyone know if someone has submitted an issue report this yet?

Comment: this video helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3WHdoz2KmE&t=103s&ab_channel=Profydev

I didn't know that you have to run the debugger in VsCode, then do `npm start` to start the application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same problem recently on Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.4.0 Preview 6.0.

This fixed it for me:

1. Right click solution > Set Startup Projects
2. (Make sure they are set to "Start" and not "start without debugging" while you are here)
3. Click Configuration Properties
4. **Change Configuration for your projects from Release to Debug.**

Might need to change these back to Release before deploying...

Comment: Tried this answer on VS2022 Version 17.5.2, but it didn't work for me.