# How to debug a C# dll project added to a Blazor solution

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have a Blazor WebAssembly solution in Visual Studio 2022. I can run and debug it fine including the C# code in the .razor file.

I have added to the solution a C# dll project that I had written some time back and from which I need to call some functions.

Everything works fine but I cannot set breakpoints in the dll code, when I do then when I run the solution the breakpoints become disabled and display the messages "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unbound breakpoint".

If I break on a call to a function in the dll from within the .razor file then I cannot step into that call, it just steps over it and I can see the result of the call in the debugger.

Would anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unbound Breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73190366/unbound-breakpoints)

Comment: If you cannot step into the code it means there is no pdb file which contains the debug data.  If it is a child project make sure you are linked to the debug folder of child and not the release folder.  the csproj file is text so you can open with notepad and easily view the referenced folders to see if you are linked to the release of debug folder.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/testing-and-debugging/